# Can't access Web of Trust (WoT) API w/ JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm new to JSON & am using VS 2013/C#. Here's the code for the request & response. Pretty straightforward, no?

```
Request request = new Request();
        //request.hosts = ListOfURLs();
        request.hosts = "www.cnn.com/www.cisco.com/www.microsoft.com/";
        request.callback = "process";
        request.key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
      //string test = "hosts=www.cnn.com/www.cisco.com/www.microsoft.com/&callback=process&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        try
        {

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)     WebRequest.Create("http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2?);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
           {
                string json = output;

                streamWriter.Write(json);
           }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        //response = true.
        //no response = false
        return true;
    }
```

When I run this, I get a 405 error indicating method not allowed.

It seems to me that there are at least two possible problems here: (1) The WoT API  (www.mywot.com/wiki/API) requires a GET request w/ a body, & httpWebRequest doesn't allow a GET in the httpWebRequest.Method; or (2) the serialized string isn't serialized properly.

NOTE: In the following I've had to remove the leading "http://" since I don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links.

It should look like:
api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2?hosts=www.cnn.com/www.cisco.com/www.microsoft.com/&callback=process&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

but instead looks like:
api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2?{"hosts":"www.cnn.com/www.cisco.com/www.microsoft.com/","callback":"process","key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}.

If I browse to:api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2?hosts=www.cnn.com/www.cisco.com/www.microsoft.com/&callback=process&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; I get the expected response.

If I browse to: api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2?{"hosts":"www.cnn.com/www.cisco.com/www.microsoft.com/","callback":"process","key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}; I get a 403 denied error.

If I hardcode the request & send as a GET like below:

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)     WebRequest.Create("api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2? + "test");  it also works as expected.

I'd appreciate any help w/ this & hope I've made the problem clear.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the problem is that you are sending JSON in the URL.  According to the [API doc](http://www.mywot.com/wiki/API) that you referenced, the API is expecting regular URL encoded parameters (not JSON), and it will *return* JSON to you in the body of the response:

> **Requests**
>
> The API consists of a number of interfaces, all of which are called using normal HTTP GET requests to api.mywot.com and return a response in XML or JSON format if successful. HTTP status codes are used for returning error information and parameters are passed using standard URL conventions. The request format is as follows:
>
> `http://api.mywot.com/version/interface?param1=value1&param2=value2`

You should not be serializing your request; you should be *deserializing* the response.  All of your tests above bear this out.